# Class Cast Exception Issue

Tags: android, xml, exception

Seeing strange behavior in my android application. I have a meter and a image view in my android xml. It was working fine and just on changing the position of the widgets in my xml graphical view am getting this `ClassCastException.` Following is my XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/halo"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".hello" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="perform" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/images" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The logcat shows me the following on application crashing:

```
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hello.hello}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 11:02:01.411: E/AndroidRuntime(21312): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
```

Can anybody please explain why is it happening in my case? and then the biggest question what's the position of widgets has to do with it??

Comment: Please paste the code of your `ComponentInfo` activity

Comment: where you using `org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView`?

Comment: are you casting Button to GaugeView

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: thank you i got it solved! answer was correct!

Comment: whats the point of voting question down when its perfectly logical??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a project cleanup. It's a common issue.

Eclipse - Project - Clean - Select your project - Ok

I'm not sure why this happens, but I guess that some times, when you move a view, it gets moved on the XML but not on the compilated code. With a project cleanup, the compilated code is regenerated and then, correctly placed.

Comment: thank you! resolved! :D +1 . But am curious to know why this actually happens! am never casting meter to image view then whats wrong with logcat?

Comment: My Guess, you swapped Button and GaugeView in your XML at some point.

Comment: @Baba I don't really know, what I know is that this just happens. And a lot if you move views around. Accept answer as correct if this solved your issue, please.

Answer (score 2):

While initialise  "org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView" custom class's object , there is problem with casting. otherwise your xml is correct if there cutom class is exist with correct package name.

check out initialisation or please add that code at here

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issues.
clean a project.and check the variable type cast in java file.

like example

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

or

```
GaugeView gv=(GaugeView)findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
```

May be solve the problm.

Answer (score 0):

You should check where you define your widgets
like

```
Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
GaugeView gv=(GaugeView)findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
Imageview iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: i have them separately!